# How to overlay an opengl scene onto ios camera feed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, opengl-es, augmented-reality

I am new to iOS development and trying to get to grips with Objective-C and Swift.

Is there a known way to render an `OpenGL` scene (i.e a cube) on top of the camera feed?

I can display a cube on screen using `OpenGLES` without a storyboard file in one project. In another project, I can capture the camera feed and display it back using `AVFoundation`, with a story board. I also have seen classes called `EAGL` and `GLKit`, but due to my lack of knowledge of iOS I cant see how these could be used.

Is there a way for these two functionalities to co-exist? Simulating a very basic Augmented Reality.

Any guidance, resources or tutorials people have to complete a similar task would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get the two to exist,  the best thing to do is start with an opengles game project.  Then select the file Main.storyboard and it will load up your interface builder.  Click on view under Game View Controller, and hit CMD + X (We want to cut it).  After this, go to the object library (Lower right corner of the right panel) and select View.  Drag this view into the Game View controller.  Then click on the view, and hit CMD + V (paste it in).  You now have a GLKView that is sitting inside of a view that you can resize to however you like that is all set up with the default GLKit code.  Now you just place your camera code in the Top level view, along with other views,  and make sure the GLKView that you now have in it stays at the bottom of the list (So that it shows on top of all other views).